# Why is my Fourier transformed matrix rotated?

Tags: image-processing, image, fourier-analysis

After Fourier transforming and shifting the zero frequency of a matrix, my outcome is rotated by 45 degrees from what it should be. Can anybody spot why?

```
ApertureSize = {300, 300}; DiscRadius = 20; PhaseDisc0 = 10; Disc1 = {50, 150}; 
PhaseDisc1 = 10; Disc2 = {150, 150}; PhaseDisc2 = 15; Disc3 = {150, 150};
PhaseDisc3 = 30; MagnificationAperture = 0.5; MagnificationFT = 0.5;

makeMask[disks_, r_, {ny_, nx_}] :=  With[{dm = Position[DiskMatrix[r], 1] - (r + 1)}, 
Apply[Plus, (Function[{pos, value},SparseArray[Select[(Map[pos + # &, dm]),
1 <= First[#] <= ny && 1 <= Last[#] <= nx &] -> value, {ny, 
    nx}]] @@@ disks)]]

masks = makeMask[{{ApertureSize/2, PhaseDisc0}, {Disc1, PhaseDisc1}, 
{Disc2, PhaseDisc2}, {Disc3, PhaseDisc3}}, DiscRadius, ApertureSize]; 
Image[masks, Magnification -> MagnificationAperture]
{nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[masks];
d = masks*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}]; 
ft = (Re[Fourier[d]])^2;
ift = Image[ft, Magnification -> MagnificationFT]
```

Comment: You need to explain why you think the output is wrong if you want to get a sane answer to your question. Why do you think the resulting FFT data is rotated by 45 degrees? How can data be "rotated by 45 degrees" if it is a 2D array, which does not support such rotations?

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Right. Well, to my understanding, this 2D array is actually 2 delta functions convoluted with a circle. The FT of convolution is multiplication of the transform of each of the functions. The 2 delta functions transform into a cosine and the circle transforms into a Bessel function of the first kind. Since the argument of the Bessel is much smaller then that of the cosine, what we should be seeing a cosine modulated by a Bessel envelope along the line connecting the centers of the two circles. Instead, we see a cosine at a 45 degree angle to that. See my problem?

Answer (score 6):

The issue here is a subtle issue: one must be careful when choosing plot ranges in order to make sure that one is getting a good picture of what the data looks like.

For starters, let's take a look at the initial `masks` data:

```
ApertureSize = {300, 
  300}; DiscRadius = 20; PhaseDisc0 = 10; Disc1 = {50, 150};
PhaseDisc1 = 10; Disc2 = {150, 150}; PhaseDisc2 = 15; Disc3 = {150, 
  150};
PhaseDisc3 = 30; MagnificationAperture = 1; MagnificationFT = 1;

makeMask[disks_, r_, {ny_, nx_}] := 
  With[{dm = Position[DiskMatrix[r], 1] - (r + 1)}, 
   Apply[Plus, (Function[{pos, value}, 
       SparseArray[
        Select[(Map[pos + # &, dm]), 
          1 <= First[#] <= ny && 1 <= Last[#] <= nx &] -> value, {ny, 
         nx}]] @@@ disks)]];
masks = makeMask[{{ApertureSize/2, PhaseDisc0}, {Disc1, 
     PhaseDisc1}, {Disc2, PhaseDisc2}, {Disc3, PhaseDisc3}}, 
   DiscRadius, ApertureSize];
MatrixPlot[masks, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

which returns

[image]

which shows that we have two disks, one of magnitude 55 and another of magnitude 10. Since $10\neq 55$, Fourier transforming `masks` should return something roughly like

$$\exp(i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{j})\frac{J_1(a|\mathbf{k}|)}{a|\mathbf{k}|}\left[\cos(b k_1)+c\exp(i d k_1)\right]$$

where the first plane wave factor arises due to the gory details of the initial translational position of the disks, the Bessel function arises from the disks, and the sum of cosine and plane wave arises from the unequal disks.

Creating an image plot of the resulting FFT with a saturated color scale gives a strange picture:

```
{nRow, nCol} = Dimensions[masks];
d = masks*(-1)^Table[i + j, {i, nRow}, {j, nCol}];
ft = (Re[Fourier[d]])^2;
ift = Image[ft, Magnification -> 3]
```

[image]

This initially seems wrong, because the stripes from the cosine term ought to cause horizontal shading, rather than diagonal shading.

However, trying again with properly scaled axes produces this:

```
ift = Image[(ft/2000)\[TensorProduct]ToPackedArray[{1.0, 0.3, 0.1}], 
  Magnification -> 3]
```

[image]

Here's a zoomed-in version:

[image]

Notice the faint horizontal stripes, which are caused by the cosine term. The diagonal stripes are some sort of very low amplitude artifact, possibly caused by imperfections in the initial disk matrix? In any case, the diagonal bands are a visual artifact, and don't actually represent an error in the data.

Another thing to watch out for is the plane wave multipler $\exp(i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{j})$, which can cause visual havoc if you are just plotting the real part, and which depends on the initial rotation of the data. You will need to consult the definition of discrete Fourier transforms to figure out how to preprocess your data if you want things to match up with the continuum Fourier transform case. However, this is a problem of mathematics, not of Mathematica, so it's sort of a separate issue to be aware of.

Comment: Wow, very cool! Thank you very much, I didn't even think in that direction...

Comment: @AsafMiron: Yeah, when I first started programming and plotting datasets, I had a lot of initial mistakes where I was plotting functions using plot-ranges which didn't make sense, and then I would get confused because stuff wasn't looking like I thought it would look like, and this is sort of one of those situations. One thing you can do is to use `PlotRange -> All` for plots that have axes, such as `ArrayPlot` or `Plot`, that way you know you'll be getting the whole picture, and not just part of it. Unfortunately, `Image` doesn't support that, so I should probably use something else.

Comment: @AsafMiron: But yeah, the key part was using `ft/2000` instead of `ft`, since `ft` was very large and was saturating the imageplot.

Comment: I definitely see your point now but 2 hours ago I was going nuts trying to think why the heck am I getting an image rotated at precisely 45 degrees!? This is actually the first code I've ever written except in a first year C course so I'm very happy it worked in the end. (Mainly due to the help I've gotten here)